# C# + WPF : text mode equivalent of old DOS libraries or curses

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

The goal: For a personal project, I'd like to simulate an old-fashioned computer interface with full screen command line, hex editor, text editor, etc.  All text, no graphics.  (For a simulator/emulator of a hypothetical computer.)

The starting point:  I've figured out that console mode can't be full-screened anymore but that I can easily go fullscreen in WPF with WindowState=Maximized and WindowStyle=None.  So I can make a full-screen TextBox.

The problem: Is there an existing control, pattern, or library for basic writing to a screen of text and reading from the keyboard (not filling out and submitting a field on a form, like a TextBox is geared toward)?

I assume that I'll need to make my own custom control instead of a textbox, and build a large class of low-level methods to position the cursor, output characters, react to input, etc.  But if there's a tried-and-true method or standard approach, I'd rather use that than burn time reinventing a commonly-used wheel.

In the olden DOS days, I would've used a library based off of direct BIOS video calls, PEEKs and POKEs to video RAM, and keyboard and mouse polling.  Of course that doesn't apply anymore, but neither do the standard console routines.  Is there something already out there that fills that niche?

[edit]

To clarify. In DOS days, we had libraries for things like:

```
Scroll(3); 
Write(24,1, "Your command has been queued for execution"); 
input = Prompt(25, 1, "Enter a command>");
```

and in document edit mode we would do things like

```
key = WaitKey(); 
switch (key) { 
  case PGUP: Scroll(-24); 
  case PGDN: Scroll(24);
  case LEFT: MoveCursor(-1,0);
  case DOWN: MoveCursor(0,1);
  // ...
}
```

etc... That's the sort of thing that I'm looking for.  Something with functions like Write, Scroll, Prompt, etc.

Comment: +1 Would be interesting to see your program once its done! =) Winforms did have a caret class, maybe there is a WPF equiv., or maybe the way WPF controls are built (lookless) you could just change the look of the cursor. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.textbox.caret.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are developing is closer to a game than a standard Windows forms application - using a game development library (such as SDL or Microsoft XNA) might make things more straightfoward.

If you are already experienced with the way that the console functioned in the days of old then implementing this should be pretty straightforward - you have your behind-the-sceenes array of characters displayed on the screen + cursor position structure which should be easy to print to the screen each frame, plus a game library will give you the ability to intercept and handle all keyboard events.

If you were planning on routing the output of another process onto this "screen" then things might start to become a little more tricky - if this is the case then this might not be the best idea.

Comment: I had considered looking into a games library.  But I'm not planning fancy 3-D real-time rendering, just plain text-mode operations that were basic in the '80s.  Strange to think that I might actually need a high level modern gaming library to do that nowadays.  But maybe that would be the easiest way...

Comment: @Ray: You don't *need* a high level game library, but it sure will make things a hell of a lot easier. However when you turn you WPF app into a XNA app you won't be able to add things like JumpList, etc. Maybe not the most important thing for a Terminal, but it's good to know what your giving up. Thats not to say XNA is bad or anything. Its just a case of different libraries being designed for different things.

Comment: @Ray It depends on the game library (I'm a fan of SDL which is almost entirely based on 2D graphics), it's just that the game library gives you complete control of the graphics - to want to achieve the same thing in WPF is slightly unusual, and so it might be a tad tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to achieve the look and feel (and responsiveness) of a text mode application using a WPF TextBox will have disappointing results. Take a look at what Pete Brown did when he created a [Commodore 64 emulator](http://10rem.net/lab/commodore-64-emulator) in WPF and Silverlight.

I believe his implementation actually used a writable bitmap to emulate a video card. So the peeks and pokes you refer to would actually take place in a memory buffer instead of the screen and then that would be turned into a screen image frame by frame.